# LINQ Cannot implicitly convert type Generic.ICollection to Generic.List

Tags: c#, linq

I have been thrown in the deep end with some software and it involves LINQ, which I am having problems with.

Background:

I need to display a list of payments relating to an organisation.

I have pulled the organisation object out of the database like this:

```
var orgDetails = Ctx.Organizations.Where(x => x.OrganizationId == orgID);
```

I have then pulled out the payments like this:

```
var orgPayments = (from payments in orgDetails.Select(x => x.ProcessedPayments) select payments);
```

Then I want to pass them into a class:

```
public class InvoiceDetails
{
    public List<ProcessedPayment> ProcessedPayment { get; set; }
    public List<InvoiceLineItems> InvoiceLineItems { get; set; }
}
```

like this:

```
InvoiceDetails InvoiceDetailModel = new InvoiceDetails
{
    ProcessedPayment = orgPayments,
    InvoiceLineItems = invoicelineitems
};
```

And I get the dreaded error:

```
LINQ Cannot implicitly convert type Generic.ICollection to Generic.List
```

I just cannot work out what I need to do to cast it to a list. I have tried changing it to

```
var orgPayments = (from payments in orgDetails.Select(x => x.ProcessedPayments) select payments).ToList();
```

With no luck

Can anyone help me find out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear why you're using a query expression at all, rather than just `var orgPayments = orgDetails.Select(x => x.ProcessedPayments).ToList()`... but are you *sure* it's the payments that's causing the problem rather than the `InvoiceLineItems`?

Comment: Are you sure adding `.ToList()` didn't work?  The error may be repeating for both properties on the object, so you may need to call `.ToList()` on the `invoicelineitems` as well.  Also, the error message should indicate a type specifier between `<>` brackets.

Comment: Additionally, I strongly suspect that's not the actual error message. Please copy and paste the *exact* error message into your question.

Comment: Do you want to pull a single organisation with your first query as right now it's giving you a list of them (with perhaps a single entry), did you mean `var orgDetails = Ctx.Organizations.Single(x => x.OrganizationId == orgID);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first query gives you a list of organisations rather than a single one which I believe is what you are looking for (assuming `OrganizationId` is your primary key.) Look at the [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx) method, it returns an `IEnumerable<>`.

So I would change it to:

```
var orgDetails = organizations.Single(x => x.OrganizationId == orgID);
```

Be aware that this will throw an exception if an organisation with `orgID` is not found so you may need to use `SingleOrDefault` instead and check that `orgDetails != null`.

Which means you don't need any further linq to get the payments and instead of creating the `orgPayments` variable, just use `orgDetails.ProcessedPayments` like this:

```
InvoiceDetails InvoiceDetailModel = new InvoiceDetails
{
    ProcessedPayment = orgDetails.ProcessedPayments,
    InvoiceLineItems = invoicelineitems
};
```

Comment: I ended up with ProcessedPayment = orgDetails.ProcessedPayments.ToList() thanks for taking the time to help me :)